# Indexing -- page ranges only when explicitly requested?

Tags: indexing

Suppose I mention Aristotle in one context at the top of page 40. And then there is a discussion of a quite different argument of Aristotle's from the bottom of page 41 to page 43. I'd like the index entry to read

> Aristotle, 40, 41–43

But putting `\index{Aristotle}` on p. 40, and then `\index{Aristotle|(}` on 41, and `\index{Aristotle|)}` on p.43 gives the unwanted

> Aristotle, 40–43

So -- headline question -- is there a way to force indexing to ONLY collapse adjacent page numbers into page ranges when EXPLICITLY told to?

I'm using the Memoir class, if that makes a difference! And apologies if I've overlooked an existing answer to what seems a pretty basic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run MakeIndex with the `-r` command line option.

In the following example I use `imakeidx` for convenience, so I can directly pass the option for the automatic call of `makeindex`.

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[options=-r]

\begin{document}

A page with a reference to \index{Aristotle}Aristotle.

\clearpage

A group of pages that describe \index{Aristotle|(}Aristotle

\clearpage

Again about Aristotle.

\clearpage

Again about \index{Aristotle|)}Aristotle.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

From the man page:

```
       -r        Disable implicit page range formation; page ranges  must  be  created  by
                 using  explicit  range operators; see SPECIAL EFFECTS below.  By default,
                 three or more successive pages are automatically abbreviated as  a  range
                 (e.g. 1--5).
```

Comment: Thanks! Very oddly, when I had tried this before I got consistent error messages, and just couldn't get `imakeidx` to play nicely. But having since cleaned up the doc's preamble removing some unused packages, all works perfectly. Heaven knows what was causing the glitch!